# Android. Autocompletetextview and sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete

I'm trying to find a solution for following thing.

Autocompletetextview with filtering on sqlite side.

I guess, I should write custom CursorAdapter, which implements Filterable, but I have no idea, where to start.

Did anybody see any examples / tutorials for that?

Mur

Comment: I found already the answer through learning by doing :) Try to write a tutorial for beginners like me

Comment: Have u found the solution cause I have the same problem..

Comment: yes, i found the solution and today i wrote a post about it as answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a post as answer to my question.

http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-autocompletetextview-with-sqlite.html

Hope it helps for someone else.